# Expressions for Analytical Solutions of the Sedov blast wave problem?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

There is a large amount of expository material out there about the self similar solution to the Sedov Blast wave problem, and I am interested in obtaining the analytical expression so I can code it up and compare it to my numerical results.

From Chapter 17 of Shu's "The Physics of Astrophysics (Vol 2)", we consider a point release of a large amount of energy $E$ into a static medium of homogenous density $\rho_1$. By self similarity arguments we can obtain a variable $\xi = r\left(\frac{\rho_1}{Et^2}\right)^{1/5}$ (17.1 of Shu) and ultimately define explicit expressions for the primitive variables of the governing equations

\begin{align}
  \rho(r, t) & = \frac{\gamma + 1}{\gamma - 1}\rho_1\alpha(\xi)  \\
  u(r, t) & = \frac{4}{5(\gamma+1)}\frac{r}{t}v(\xi) \\
  P(r, t) & = \frac{8}{25(\gamma + 1)}\rho_1\left(\frac{r}{t}\right)^2p(\xi)
\end{align}

where $\gamma = 1.4$ (17.10-17.12 of Shu). He then goes on to say that Sedov (miraculously!) derived analytical expressions for $\alpha(\xi), v(\xi), p(\xi)$.

There are multiple writeups that give that present the same equations with slightly different notation, and then pass the buck to Sedov's original monograph for these expressions. Such as equations (5.23)-(5.25) of [http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~ryden/ast825/ch5-6.pdf](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/%7Eryden/ast825/ch5-6.pdf), or (10.17) - (10.20) of [https://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/num_fluid_2011/Chapter_10.pdf](https://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Edullemond/lectures/num_fluid_2011/Chapter_10.pdf). The notes http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2012/1217.2.K.pdf mention that these expressions can be found in Section 99 of Landau and Lifshitz. I looked there and in Sedov's Monograph and am not able to easily tell what they should be.

Can somebody help me make this more explicit? My background is in numerics so this literature is all quite unfamiliar to me.